# Writing a DF as a parquet with null values using Spark

Tags: java, csv, parquet, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a CSV using a Struct Type with more Struct Fields than the CSV file has columns. This results in the extraneous columns being null. When trying to write this file out as a parquet I am getting a java.lang.NumberFormatException: null.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:404)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
at     scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:230)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:31)
at com.databricks.spark.csv.util.TypeCast$.castTo(TypeCast.scala:54)
at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$6.apply(CsvRelation.scala:181)
at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$6.apply(CsvRelation.scala:162)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

dataFrameWithNulls.coalesce(4).write.option("mode","PERMISSIVE").mode("append").partitionBy("$day", "$hour").parquet(s"$writeDir/")